# android - Service not restarted after killed in KitKat

Tags: android, service

My service doesn't get restarted on KitKat devices whenever I close the application. Note that I'm using the START_STICKY flag.

**This is my service**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("Script", "onCreate()");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    this.context = this;
    Log.i("Script", "flags: "+flags);
    Log.i("Script", "startId: "+startId);
    Log.e("active","active");

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

In Manifest

```
 <service
        android:name=".TimerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        >
 </service>
```

On Lollipop and Marshmallow devices, I'm using a *JOB SCHEDULER* and is working fine.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Did you mean restated or restarted?

Comment: @ShellZero restarted. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());

```
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Objects.requireNonNull(alarmService).set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +1000, restartServicePI);
```